# Why is binary_search not working as expected?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, binary-search

The question is to find the index of first element in the array that repeats itself atleast once in the array.

Input:

7

1 3 4 5 3 7 2

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int a[n], curr = -1;
    int num = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = a[i];
        a[i] = -1;
        if (binary_search(a, a + num, x))
        {
            curr = i;
            cout << curr << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << curr + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:
2
(As 3 is the first element to appear twice in the array)

Output received:
0

Comment: Off topic: whatever resource you are using to learn C++, stop using it immediately. `bits/stdc++` isn't a standard header, and should never be used. Arrays must have compile time constant sizes, not user specified. And never use namespace std.

Comment: `num` is going to have the wrong value, btw. Just use `n`, which already contains the number of elements.

Comment: Also, since this `int a[n]` is not a valid C++ array, doing this: `binary_search(a, a + num, x)`, where you are adding `num` to `a` is ... we don't know if that actually does what it says.  As a matter of fact, certain compilers that allowed the non-standard syntax of `int a[n]` did not work with STL algorithm functions.  Instead, weird syntax errors were given when using arrays in this manner.

Comment: Binary search assumes a sorted range.  You are not supplying it a sorted range, so its behaviour is undefined.   Also, `int a[n]` where `n` is a variable is not valid in standard C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cin >> n;
>
> int a[n]
> ```

This isn't allowed in C++. The size of an array variable must be compile time constant. `n` is not compile time constant. To create an array of runtime length, you must allocate it dynamically. Simplest solution is to use `std::vector`,

> ```
> int num = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
> ```

Use `std::size(a)` to get the size of an array instead. However, in this case, just use `n`.

> ```
> binary_search(a, a + num, x)
> ```

The input range must be partially sorted in order to use `std::binary_search` with respect of the searched number. Since you use potentially all elements as the searched number, this effectively means that the array must be fully sorted.

> Input:
>
> ```
> 7
>
> 1 3 4 5 3 7 2
> ```

Your input array is not fully sorted. As result of violating the pre-condition, the behaviour of the program is undefined.